# How can I manually control the progress of the @ngx-progressbar/core progress bar in Angular5/Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progress-bar

I am trying to get a progress bar in my application. I found the @ngx-progressbar/core which looks promising. But for some reason, I can't manage to control it's progress. Whatever I do, as soon as the progress increases some, it just increases all the way in leaps and bounds without any control. I was hoping to increase it in steps from observables.

This is what I tried now, with Ionic, but that shouldn't really matter as it is basically just Angular. I am using version 4.3 of @ngx-progressbar/core and Angular 5 and Ionic 4.

The component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NgProgressComponent } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(NgProgressComponent) progress: NgProgressComponent;


  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("Starting progress");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
  }
```

The template:

```
<ion-content>
  <ng-progress></ng-progress>
  <button ion-button color="primary" outline round (click)="this.progress.inc(5);">Inc</button>
</ion-content>
```

I was expecting the progress bar to increase by 5% with every click, but as soon as I click it, no matter what the argument to progress.inc() is, it just starts to fill the whole progress bar. If I .start() the progress bar, it fills up straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set` method for manual control:

```
progress = 0;

setProgress(){
    this.progress.set(this.progress += 5);
}
```

Comment: .inc(x) should do the same right? It should increment the progress bar with x amount, while .set(x) should set it directly to x. But at least .inc(x) makes it just continue incrementing. Or do I misunderstand the meaning of .inc()?

Comment: Yes .inc(x) continues I incrementing by x. I thought you didn't want that.

Comment: Neither work. When I call .inc(), the progressbar completes all the way, it doesn't just increase by 5%. I just gave up on it and made my own angular/ionic component.